# Discord bot in python wont allow some emojis

Tags: python, discord, bots, emoji

I don't know if this is a problem with just me but I tried to use an emoji for my discord bot using python and it worked fine. However, some emojis are not working and instead give me an error

This is the code will send emojis and works with the one in the code but then when i try different emojis it breaks

message.add_reaction("\U0001F92E")

I tried to get the black box emoji and got this error:

"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-8: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

Why I'm confused is the exact same piece of code works with a different emoji so I am clueless why the one I'm trying to use breaks.

Comment: Please post the code and error here.

Comment: I changed my question to make the error easy to make out. I also put the line of code that’s causing the problem. It’s not that code I think it’s the actual emoji Unicode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

#### `message.add_reaction(u"\U0001F92E")`

(See https://discordnet.dev/guides/emoji/emoji.html#emoji.)

When trying to use unicode, you need to be careful with **escape character**.

For more, when you look at the path `C:\Users\blah\blah` and the unicode `\U000XXX`, it basically regards it as unicode. So when using path, you need to use like `C:\\Users\\blah\blah`.

Comment: square = u'\U00025FC'
      grid = [[square,square,square], [square,square,square], [square,square,square]]                 this didnt work......

Comment: Could you provide the whole code that caused this issue then? Like @Soumendra just mentioned?

Comment: I dont see why the full code is necessary as the code works with other emojis so Im pretty sure its not my code. I think its logic.